# Any category created does not show the title Correctly

Tags: category-attribute

i have a problem, any category created in my store not show the correct page titles, for example:
Page title in category: **"Smartphone Sony"**
What appears in the title of the page ....: **"sign in now by clicking here"**

What can be? I'm using the default theme, and the files are unchanged. researching I realized I could be the file catalog/category/view.phtml on line 43:
`<div class="page-title category-title">
    <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>`

But it is typical .... what can it be? thank you

Comment: Can you run a quick check to confirm whether the text is coming from the category or elsewhere. Can you take a look in the _catalog_category_entity_varchar_ table and confirm that the title that you are seeing is not in there.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry("current_category");

//Display the current Category Title
echo $currentCategory->getName();
```

need to reindex and clear the cache.

> Note:- reindex requires.

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score -1):

1) please check your Magento logs, maybe there you can find something useful
2) please check if you have proper & valid HTML code, I suppose issue might be somewhere out of your category view template...

P.S. is it clean Magento?